# Entire array interpreted as last element in array

Tags: jquery, django, json

I've executed the following statement in my js console:

```
$.post('/cp/remove-organizers/', {email_list:['test@test.org','test2@test.org']})
```

In my view, I then print out the value of `request.POST`, and I get:

```
<QueryDict: {u'email_list[]': [u'test@test.org', u'test2@test.org']}>
```

Nothing out of the ordinary, right? Here's the thing: printing the value of `request.POST['email_list[]']` (or alternatively, `request.POST.values()` returns:

`u'test2@test.org'`

Why does this happen, and what can I do to return the entire array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to retrieve multiple values.

```
request.POST.getlist('email_list[]')
```

This is [documented behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__):

> If the key has more than one value, `__getitem__`() returns the last value.